# Regex in SQL to extract the function implementation?

Tags: sql, regex, github, google-bigquery

I have to query the github content to find the implementation of a particular function add. The content which I have extracted using the following SQL query:

```
(function(f){if(typeof exports==="object"&&typeof module!=="undefined")

{module.exports=f()}else if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define([],f)}else{var g;if(typeof window!=="undefined"){g=window}else if(typeof global!=="undefined"){g=global}else if(typeof self!=="undefined"){g=self}else{g=this}g.ngContextmenu = f()}})(function(){var define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(_dereq_,module,exports){
    'use strict';

    angular.module('io.dennis.contextmenu')
    .directive('contextmenuContainer', Container);

    function Container() {
      return {
        scope: {
          contextmenu: '=contextmenuContainer'
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: ['$scope', ContainerCtrl]
      };
    .
    .
    .
    .
      function add(entry) {
        if (!isSelected(entry)) {
          selected.unshift(entry);
          toggleSelected(entry.element, true);
        }
        pub.item = selected[0].item;
      }

      function remove(entry) {
        var index = selected.indexOf(entry);
        if (index > -1) {
          selected.splice(index, 1);
        }
        toggleSelected(entry.element, false);
      }

     .
    .
    .
      function toggle(entry, multi) {
        multi = multi || false;
        var isEntrySelected = isSelected(entry);

        if (isEntrySelected) {
          remove(entry);

        } else {

          if (!multi) { clear(); }
          add(entry);
        }
      }

      function clear() {
        angular.forEach(selected, function(entry) {
          toggleSelected(entry.element, false);
        });
        selected = [];
      }

      function getListOfIds(limit, path) {
        path = path || 'item.id';
        limit = Math.min(limit || selected.length, selected.length);
        var list = selected.slice(0, limit).map(function(entry) {
          return safeGet(entry, path, '');
        });
        var asString = list.join(', ');
        return (limit < selected.length) ? asString + '..' : asString;
      }

      function toggleSelected(element, forceState) {
        element.toggleClass('selected', forceState);
      }

      function safeGet(obj, path, _default) {

        if (!obj) {
          return _default;
        }

        if (!path || !String(path).length) {
          return obj;
        }

        var keys = (angular.isArray(path)) ? path : path.split('.');
        var next = keys.shift();
        return get(obj[next], keys, _default);
      }
    }

    },{}]},{},[4])(4)
    });
```

There are more rows like this. The query I am using is :

```
SELECT
  content,
  id
FROM
  [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_contents]
  WHERE
  content CONTAINS 'function add('
  AND sample_path LIKE '%.js'
  LIMIT  40;
```

How can I modify the above query so that I only can extract the content which has output for the implementation of function "add" i.e

```
function add(entry) {
    if (!isSelected(entry)) {
      selected.unshift(entry);
      toggleSelected(entry.element, true);
    }
    pub.item = selected[0].item;
  }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I think you'll have a hard time just using a regular expression. Perhaps if you wrote a [JavaScript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) you could parse the contents. Note that BigQuery supports two SQL dialects, and you are using legacy SQL in your example, whereas the link above is for standard SQL.

Comment: I have modified the query as 
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(content,r'add\(.*{(.|\n)*}\n{2,}'), id
FROM
(

SELECT
      content,
      id
    FROM
      [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_contents]
      WHERE
      content CONTAINS 'function add('
      AND sample_path LIKE '%.js'
      LIMIT  40
      )

But maybe I am missing out on something. Can someone help?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard, Can you give the JS udf?

Comment: Can you provide data in your output which doesn't match your need and you want to filter out, It's not very clear for your question what exactly is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's an overly simplified version of a JavaScript UDF, which isn't even trying to match braces but I believe you get the point. I left comments in JavaScript code for you to complete the non-trivial-finding-the-end-of-the-function work. Enjoy!

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  filter_add(code STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS """
  // find start, TODO: there may be multiple function add() in single file, handle in a loop
  var start = code.indexOf('function add(');
  // TODO: count open braces and close braces to decide where function definition ends.
  // Note that braces may be in 1) single-line comment; 2) multi-line comments; 3) part of string or char literal
  var end = code.indexOf('}', start);
  return code.substr(start, end-start+1);
  """ ;
SELECT
  filter_add(content), id
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data`.github_repos.sample_contents
WHERE
  STRPOS(content, 'function add(') != 0
  AND sample_path LIKE '%.js'
LIMIT 10;
```